Spring Boot 2.7 to 3 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor
I am trying to migrate Spring Boot in my project's application, from version 2.7 to version 3. I've upgraded already bunch of dependencies and changed javax libraries to jakarta.
Currently I have problem with loading Application Context while running some unit tests.
There is a call stack as below:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for .............................................................................................................................................................................................

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate import sql command extractor [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.script.SqlScriptExtractorInitiator.instantiateExplicitCommandExtractor(SqlScriptExtractorInitiator.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.script.SqlScriptExtractorInitiator.initiateService(SqlScriptExtractorInitiator.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.script.SqlScriptExtractorInitiator.initiateService(SqlScriptExtractorInitiator.java:21)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:255)
    ... 102 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.script.SqlScriptExtractorInitiator.instantiateExplicitCommandExtractor(SqlScriptExtractorInitiator.java:58)
    ... 106 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:210)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:120)
    ... 107 more

What I understand from the call stack, is that Application Context tried to load MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor.class from library's package: org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl, but didn't manage to find the class.
I've updated the hibernate-core dependency in pom.xml from version 5.6.15.FINAL (which had class that I mentioned in its package) to version 6.1.5.FINAL.
I've seen in hibernate-core documentation in page: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core-jakarta/latest/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor.html
that this class is deprecated, so I suspect that it is not included in newer hibernate-core versions.
Has anyone faced similar issue while migrating to Spring Boot 3? Would it be enough if I find the proper hibernate-core version or maybe it is connected with something else than just dependency upgrade?
I would be grateful for any advice.
I tried some different version of hibernate-core package: 6.1.5.FINAL, 6.1.7.FINAL

As the deprecated message says: Use MultiLineSqlScriptExtractor instead.

If you use spring-boot-starter-data-jpa you should not need any hibernate dependencies.

I used your both suggestions:

changed context properties from org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor to org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.script.MultiLineSqlScriptExtractor
removed hibernate-core dependency and added spring-boot-starter-data-jpa,

I'm having different exception in logs, but it seems that those two resolved current issue, thanks!
